# Stray Input Capacltance Compensatlon with constant-GBP OpAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier, stability, compensation

In the book: Design with operational amplifiers and analog integrated circuits, section 8.2, it shows a circuit as below:

[image]

And give:

$$f_{z} = \frac{1}{2\pi(R_{1}||R_{2})(C_{n}+C_{f})},\:f_{p}=\frac{1}{2\pi R_{2} C_{f}}
$$

And the locations of fz and fp are shown at right. Apparently, it assumes fz is lower than fp.

Actually, because this is a amplifier circuit, so R2 may much greater than R1, and we may choose a Cf much greater than Cn (Cn is the stray capacitance at the inverting input terminal, usually small). Then the zero can be approximated as:

$$f_{z} \approx \frac{1}{2\pi R_{1}C_{f}} $$

Because R2 is bigger than R1, so we can choose a R2 big enought to get a fz greater than fp. Is it stable or not in this situation? The textbook don't mention this. Or simply, can I choose a much bigger Cf to move fp lower than fz, what's the cons and pros?

Comment: What is your objective? Unless you want it to roll off early, you'd normally want Cf * R2 = Cn * R1, so Cf << Cn if R2 >> R1. IOW if Cn is 10pF, R1 = 1M R2 = 20M, you would have Cf = 0.5pF.

Comment: Yes, I can choose a Cf to just make a *flat* close-loop gain. But I just curious that, this is a *normal* situation, but the text just don't mention that. Choose a bigger Cf, should make the circuit stable, although it may reduce the gain width. Am I right?

Comment: More stable with a bigger cap.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Cn normally is very small, in the pfs range. So if I don't care the loss of bandwidth, I may simply choose a bigger Cf off the shelf ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If R2 is increased with respect to R1, your gain at low frequencies increases because the gain is -R2/R1 and your op amp may saturate at low frequency.  Instability occurs when the phase shift between the output and the negative input approaches 180 degrees with a gain of more than 1.  The Gain-Bandwidth Product tells only part of the story; there is a phase shift through the op amp that is dependent on both gain and frequency.  You will not have significant phase shift inside the op amp itself unless the frequency is high.  For modern op amps, instability will almost never occur with your circuit if you stay out of saturation, because almost any value of Cf will dominate Cn and also reduce the high frequency gain where internal phase shift will occur.  For all practical purposes you can ignore Cn for values of Cf above a few hundred picofarads for a mid-range, vanilla op amp.